# Using memcached in laravel. Is it normal application behavior?

Tags: laravel, memcached

Few words about my environment:

- laravel 8;
- osx bug sur,
- mamp, php7.4.2 (with igbinary.so, memcached.so)
- memcached (have installed with brew install memached)

When I starts the memcached demon and use test route to `set()` and `get()` data from memcached everything works properly.

But when I manually stops the memcached deamon, i want to see connection error exception in my app! Telnet said that connection is refused, but blank laravel app is still working (`get()` returns `null`, but no exception has been thrown).

What am I doing wrong? I want to see my exception)) Can any one help me? As I expect the application behaviour should be throwing an exception.
Sample:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    $cache = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::store('memcached');
    $cache->put('asd','asdasdasd asdas d ',3600); # this line returns false, but as I expects should throw an excpetion when memcached is down
    dump($cache->get('asd'));
});
```

Comment: "but no exception has been thrown" Show the code.

Comment: @Tpojka I have updated my question with sample code

Comment: So (just to be clear), after you disconnect memcached server you then make request to that route?

Comment: Exactly! memcached service is stoped, 11211 port is not listening anymore. In such case i expect that should be thrown connection exception. The situation is similar as with database, when it's demon is stoped.  Database connection would throws an exception, and memcached - not!

Comment: Maybe you would like to make a global middleware where you would check if `!is_null($connectionId);`.

Comment: I', just asking about application behaviour. Because if redis or database is down, i'm getting an exception, but with memcached - not. So my primary question sounds: Is it normal application behavior when application do not throws exception when memcahed is down?